# Vector subscript out of range in SFML game, but no vectors were created

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

I am writing a simple isometric game - simulator of town development. The main classes are Player class and World class. So, the problem is, that when I launching my game, all seems to be going as planned, but when I want to click "X" to close it, at the moment cursor reach place, in which red arrow points, program is being breaked this error.

[image]

It is not happening, when Player object is not created, so I think some problem in it.

**Player.hpp:**

```
#ifndef PLAYER_HEADER
#define PLAYER_HEADER

#include "Main.hpp"
#include "ToScreenF.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class Player
{
public:
    sf::Vector2i MousePos;
    sf::Vector2i inCell;
    sf::Vector2i cellOffset;
    sf::Vector2i cellSelected;

    sf::Vector2f cellSelectedInWorldSpace;

    sf::Image selectedTileImage;
    sf::Texture selectedTileTexture;
    sf::Sprite selectedTileSprite;

    sf::Image CheatImage;

    sf::Color color;

    Player(std::string FILE);
    ~Player();

    void Update(sf::RenderWindow* Window, sf::Vector2f TileSize, sf::Vector2f vOrigin, int WorldWidth, int WorldHeight);
};

#endif PLAYER_HEADER
```

**Player.cpp:**

```
#include "Player.hpp"

Player::Player(std::string FILE)
{
    selectedTileImage.loadFromFile(FILE);
    selectedTileImage.createMaskFromColor(sf::Color::White);
    selectedTileTexture.loadFromImage(selectedTileImage);
    selectedTileSprite.setTexture(selectedTileTexture);
    CheatImage.loadFromFile("tileCheat.png");
}
void Player::Update(sf::RenderWindow* Window, sf::Vector2f TileSize, sf::Vector2f vOrigin, int WorldWidth, int WorldHeight)
{    
    MousePos = {sf::Mouse::getPosition((*Window))};
    inCell = {(int)(MousePos.x / TileSize.x), (int)(MousePos.y / TileSize.y) };
    cellOffset = { MousePos.x % (int)TileSize.x, MousePos.y % (int)TileSize.y };
    cellSelected = { 
        (inCell.y - (int)vOrigin.y) + (inCell.x - (int)vOrigin.x),
        (inCell.y - (int)vOrigin.y) - (inCell.x - (int)vOrigin.x) 
    };
    color = CheatImage.getPixel(cellOffset.x, cellOffset.y);
    if (color == sf::Color::Red) { cellSelected.x += -1; cellSelected.y += 0; };
    if (color == sf::Color::Blue) { cellSelected.x += 0; cellSelected.y += -1; };
    if (color == sf::Color::Green) { cellSelected.x += 0; cellSelected.y += 1; };
    if (color == sf::Color::Yellow) { cellSelected.x += 1; cellSelected.y += 0; };
    if (cellSelected.x < 0) cellSelected.x = 0;
    if (cellSelected.x > (WorldWidth - 1)) cellSelected.x = 19;
    if (cellSelected.y < 0) cellSelected.y = 0;
    if (cellSelected.y > (WorldHeight - 1)) cellSelected.y = 19;
    cellSelectedInWorldSpace = ToScreen(cellSelected.x, cellSelected.y, TileSize, vOrigin);
    selectedTileSprite.setPosition(cellSelectedInWorldSpace);
    Window->draw(selectedTileSprite);
    std::cout << cellSelected.x << " " << cellSelected.y << std::endl;
}
```

**ToScreenF.cpp:**

```
#include "ToScreenF.hpp"

sf::Vector2f ToScreen(int x, int y, sf::Vector2f TileSize, sf::Vector2f vOrigin)
{
    return sf::Vector2f
    {
        (vOrigin.x * TileSize.x) + (x - y) * (TileSize.x / 2),
        (vOrigin.y * TileSize.y) + (x + y) * (TileSize.y / 2)
    };
}
```

**TApplication.hpp:**

```
    #ifndef TAPPLICATION_HEADER
    #define TAPPLICATION_HEADER
    
    #include "Main.hpp"
    #include "World.hpp"
    #include "Player.hpp"
    
    namespace Application
    {
        class TApplication
        {
        protected:
            sf::RenderWindow *Window;
            World *GameWorld;
            Player* _Player;
    
        public:
            TApplication();
            ~TApplication();
    
            void Init();
            void Run();
            void End();
        };
    }
```

**TApplication.cpp:**

```
#include "TApplication.hpp"

namespace Application
{
    TApplication::TApplication() : Window(nullptr)
    {
    
    }

    TApplication:: ~TApplication()
    {

    }

    void TApplication::Init()
    {
        if (Window == nullptr)
            Window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(1200, 800), "Town Builder Simulator");
            GameWorld = new World("BasicTile.png", 100, 100);
            _Player = new Player("selectedTile.png");
    }

    void TApplication::Run()
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (Window->isOpen())
        {
            while(Window->pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                {
                    Window->close();
                }
            }

            Window->clear();
            GameWorld->Draw(Window);
            _Player->Update(Window, sf::Vector2f(40, 20), sf::Vector2f(10, 10), GameWorld->WorldWidth, GameWorld->WorldHeight);
            Window->display();
        }
    }

    void TApplication::End()
    {
        if (Window != nullptr)
        {
            delete Window;
            delete GameWorld;
            Window = nullptr;
        }
    }
}

**Main.hpp**
#ifndef MAIN_HEADER
#define MAIN_HEADER

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

#endif
```

Thanks in advance all who helped me, I am very grateful!)

Comment: Seems you have memory corruption, but it's pretty much impossible to tell why from the small amount of code posted.

Comment: In particular, what is going on in the destructor of `Player`?

Comment: Click retry and you'll end up in the debugger. Look at the call stack to try and find your code then examine the state of the program at that point to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: @john Without Player object all works, thus I didn't posted any code except Player class code. I also can post code where Player object is creating.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Actually nothing,  I just forgot to decribe it. Now I done it and it does not helped.

Comment: @luk_chesnok_xren Do not code empty destructors.  Either declare them as `= default;` or remove them.  Writing empty destructors changes the traits of the class, maybe enough so that the compiler will produce less than optimal code.

Comment: @luk_chesnok_xren -- So when you looked at the call stack, what function did *you* create that shows up in the call stack?  That is where the error originates.

Comment: @luk_chesnok_xren I don't know SFML but looking at the code you have posted now I wonder about what happens when the window is closed. The four lines of code at the end of your while loop (starting with `Window->clear(); ...`) get executed once **after** the window has been closed. I wonder if that is the cause of the problem. Just a theory, as I said I don't know SFML.

Comment: Can it be an problem with my computer, maybe?